# Unable to Connect to Spotify Api :Error Invalid URI Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api, spotify

I am using the following two files attached.

index2.html file located on the local server which is calling the JavaScript file which is also located on the local machine

fetch-ajax3.js - JavaScript file located on the local server consisting of the function and method to authenticate and authorize the API call and retreive data and post it in the console.

I am not sure what to input in redirect URI.
Can someone help?

Resolution - i was able to resolve the issue after whitelisting the callback uri in the spotify api app.

```js
const hash = window.location.hash
.substring(1)
.split('&')
.reduce(function (initial, item) {
  if (item) {
    var parts = item.split('=');
    initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
  }
  return initial;
}, {});
window.location.hash = '';

// Set token
let _token = hash.access_token;

const authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

// Replace with your app's client ID, redirect URI and desired scopes
const clientId = '';
const redirectUri = '';
const scopes = [
  'user-top-read'
];

// If there is no token, redirect to Spotify authorization
if (!_token) {
  window.location = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join('%20')}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
}

// Make a call using the token
$.ajax({
   url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists",
   type: "GET",
   beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _token );},
   success: function(data) {
     // Do something with the returned data
     data.items.map(function(artist) {
       let item = $('<li>' + artist.name + '</li>');
       item.appendTo($('#top-artists'));
     });
   }
});
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Spotify Implicit Grant Template</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://sp-bootstrap.global.ssl.fastly.net/8.0.0/sp-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="./fetch-ajax3.js" defer></script>
      </head>
      <body class="container">
        <h1 class="text-salmon">Spotify Implicit Grant Template</h1>
        <h3>This app uses the implicit grant authorization flow to authenticate users and get user data.</h3>
        <p>
          Here are your top artists on Spotify:
          <ol id="top-artists"></ol>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you debugged your own code or done any research? If so you should share that in the question with an [edit]. Remember that SE is a terrible debugger.

Answer (score 0):

After whitelisting the callback url in the app , i was able to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

specify your URL as Http for localhost in the app settings in your Spotify dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your URL in Redirect URI which will whitelist your URL. It works for me.